# How to prove $\Bbb R^n$ is connected?

Tags: calculus, general-topology

The question requires to prove this by using the following theorem:

> If $S\subset \Bbb R^n$ is arc wise connected, then $S$ is connected.

Comment: if it is not connected, you can find a path betwen two points that isn't connected

Comment: Come again, @Maximiliano ? Perhaps you meant to say that if $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ isn't connected then there exist two points there which cannot be connected by a path?

Comment: To show that $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is arc-connected, note that any two points $x$ and $y$ can be joined by a straight line segment, $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$, where $f(\lambda)= (1-\lambda)x+\lambda y$.  And since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is arc-connected, it is connected, by the theorem you stated.  (Indeed, it is sufficient for it to be path-connected.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: every point in $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ can be connected by a straight line to the origin...

Comment: What do you really mean here? @DonAntonio

Comment: Sir could you please elaborate. As every point is connected by straight line to the origin so, there exists a path between any two points. So $\mathbb{R^n}$ is path connected and hence connected. I don't know am I correct or not...

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Exactly so.

Comment: Sir, thank you so much. Sir in case of $n=1,2$ we can easily give definition of path between two points in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Sir how to give definition of path when $n≥3$ ?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Exactly the same. For a point $\;P=(x_1,...,x_n)\;$, the line between $\;P\;$ and the origin $\;\mathcal O=(0,0,...,0)\;$ is given, for example by $$t\mathcal O+(1-t)P=\left((1-t)x_1,\,(1-t)x_2,...,(1-t)x_n\right)\,,\;\;0\le t\le 1$$ and very similar from the origini to a point...that's all !

Answer (score 2):

I completely missed the question the first time around:

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Define $\gamma(t) = x + t(y-x)$. Then $\gamma$ is continuous, $\gamma(0) = x, \gamma(1) = y$ and $\gamma(t) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Hence $\mathbb{R}^2$ is arc-wise connected.

My old answer (Showing that if $S$ is path connected then it is connected):

Suppose $U,V$ are open, disjoint and $S \subset U \cup V$. We will show that the only way this can be true is if $S$ is wholly contained in either $U$ or $V$, which will imply that $S$ is connected.

Suppose $x\in S \cap U$, $y \in S $, and let $\gamma_y$ be a path joining them, we can take $\gamma_y(0) = x, \gamma_y(1) = y$.

Let $T_y = \sup \{ t | \gamma_y(\tau) \in U \ \forall \tau \in [0,t] \}$. Note that we must have $\gamma_y(T_y) \in U$ becauseotherwise, since $V$ is open, we would have $\gamma(t) \in V$ for some neighborhood of $t=T_y$, which would contradict the definition of $T_y$. Furthermore, since $U$ is open, we must have $T_y = 1$, because otherwise, since $U$ is open, the definition of $T_y$ would be contradicted.

Hence we have $y=\gamma_y(1) \in U$ for all $y \in S$, that is, $S \subset U$. Hence $S$ is connected.